# Set Scroll Boundaries UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView which displays a webpage. The problem is I only want it to display a part of the webpage. I tried using `[[_menuWebView scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 100)];` to set the content offset to where I want it, but the problem is that I don't want the user to be able to scroll around the rest of the webpage. I also cannot set the webpage to not be scrollable because the part that I need to be able to be seen is slightly bigger than the space available. Is there a way to either:

1. Resize the view to only show one small portion so I can set it to not be scrollable
2. Set the scrolling boundaries in some way so that the user cannot scroll to the top of the page and not too far to the bottom either.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I have used the code in the answer to get the UIWebView to not scroll past the top, the problem is getting it not to scroll past the bottom. I use this code to check where the contentOffset should be if it has hit the bottom: `_bottom_y = [[_menuWebView scrollView] contentSize].height - 20 - [_menuWebView frame].size.height;`. When I NSLog _bottom_y it comes up with 68 as where the bottom offset should be. The problem is that the top offset I know to be 115 and that works. What is wrong with the code above? Why is it giving me this weird number?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to set a boundary on the bottom as well, then you need to calculate _bottom_y differently. (_menuWebView.scrollView.contentOffset.y + _menuWebView.scrollView.bounds.size.height) would be your _bottom_y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will be a good answer to your question. `UIWebView` in its structure contains an `UIScrollView`, that is why you can set your `UIViewController` to be a delegate of `UIScrollView`. Thus you can implement a method called `scrollViewDidScroll:` where you check if the `UIWebView` reached its y offset and if yes -> not let it scroll past that point.

Here is an example, that I have used:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];
    _webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 50);
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 50) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 50);
    }
}

@end
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. One quick aesthetic question: Is there a way to have the scroll bar on the side fixed so that its bounds are also the same.

Comment: Also your answer created another problem. Please see the edit.